# Kotlin Coroutines Run blocking not working as expected and Cannot block execution of for loops

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

In my app i'm executing two for loops however those for loops need to scheduled in a order here is the use case:

There are two for loops :
1- ImageStickerslist
2-TextStickerslist

What i want to do is after imagestickerslist if properly finised only then textstickerslist will be executed.

Here imagesticker list consists of url path which is used to load images from glide however if those images are of high resolution it eventually makes the thread continue even if the image is not yet loaded from url. To solve this tried adding blocking calls to glide on ready and full method but it won't prove to be of any help. I'm very confused how blocking calls work any help into this will be really appreciated.

Here's my code where for loops are executed:

```
 runBlocking {
                            launch {
                                imagestickers.forEach {
                                    runBlocking {
                                        var image = it.path
                                        var x = it.x
                                        var y = it.y
                                        image!!.log()
                                        setimagestickers(image!!, x!!, y!!, it.width!!, it.height!!)
                                    }
                                }
                            }.join()
                            textstickers.forEach {
                                runBlocking {
                                    var text = it.text.toString()
                                    var color = it.color
                                    var font = it.font
                                    var size = it.size
                                    var x = it.x
                                    var y = it.y
                                    setTextSticker(text, Color.parseColor(color), size!!, x!!, y!!)
                                }
                            }
                        }
```

Here are my two methods where main computation is taking place:

```
 fun setimagestickers(path:String,x:Int,y:Int,w:Int,h:Int){

           Glide.with(this@NewStickerActivity).asBitmap().timeout(6000000).load(path).into(object : CustomTarget<Bitmap>() {
               override fun onLoadCleared(placeholder: Drawable?) {

               }

               override fun onResourceReady(resource: Bitmap, transition: Transition<in Bitmap>?) {
                   var size: ViewGroup.LayoutParams
                   var bmp1 = resource
                   size = UiHelper.getHeightWidth(this@NewStickerActivity, (w).toInt(), (h).toInt())
                   var resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp1, size.width, size.height, false)
                   var drawable = BitmapDrawable(resources, resizedBitmap)
                   var dsImageSticker = DrawableSticker(drawable)
                   dsImageSticker.setTag("ImageSticker")
                   var pm: List<Int>
                   if (density > 3.0) {
                       pm = UiHelper.getmargins(this@NewStickerActivity, (x).toInt(), (y).toInt())
                   } else {
                       pm = UiHelper.getmargins(this@NewStickerActivity, (x).toInt(), (y).toInt())
                   }
                   Log.i("Hmmm:", pm.get(0).toFloat().toString() + "::" + pm.get(1).toFloat().toString())

                   stickerView.addStickerAndSetMatrix1(
                           dsImageSticker,
                           pm.get(0).toFloat(),
                           pm.get(1).toFloat()
                   )

               }

           })
    }
   fun setTextSticker(text: String, color: Int,size: Int, x: Int, y: Int){
            val bmp1: Bitmap
            val drawable: Drawable
            var l: List<Int>
            if (density > 3.0) {
                l = UiHelper.getmargins(this@NewStickerActivity, (x).toInt(), (y * 1.07).toInt())
            } else {
                l = UiHelper.getmargins(this@NewStickerActivity, x.toInt(), y.toInt())
            }
            //var tf = Typeface.createFromFile(assets,"fonts/"+path)
            var tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(assets, "fonts/Myriad Pro Bold SemiExtended.ttf")
            bmp1 = createBitmapFromLayoutWithText(this@NewStickerActivity, size, text, color, 0f, tf, 0f, 0f, color, Gravity.LEFT)
            drawable = BitmapDrawable(resources, bmp1)
            var dsTextSticker = DrawableSticker(drawable)
            dsTextSticker.setTag("textSticker")
            Log.i("Hmmm:", l.get(0).toFloat().toString() + "::" + l.get(1).toFloat().toString())
            /*if (rotate) {
                stic.addStickerAndSetrotate(
                        dsTextSticker, rotationdegress,
                        l.get(0).toFloat(),
                        l.get(1).toFloat()
                )
            } else {*/
            stickerView.addStickerAndSetMatrix1(
                    dsTextSticker,
                    l.get(0).toFloat(),
                    l.get(1).toFloat())



    }
```

**UPDATE**:

I got this working without coroutines by incrementing and fetching images in a sequence: 
Firstly i took a Int and then kept incrementing until it reached list size here is my code:
Firstly i did this :

```
var i = 0 
setimagestickers(imagestickers.get(i).path!!, imagestickers.get(i).x!!, imagestickers.get(i).y!!, imagestickers.get(i).width!!, imagestickers.get(i).height!!)
```

After that inside on resource ready did the trick!!

```
Glide.with(this@NewStickerActivity).asBitmap().timeout(6000000).load(path).into(object : CustomTarget<Bitmap>() {
               override fun onLoadCleared(placeholder: Drawable?) {

               }

               override fun onResourceReady(resource: Bitmap, transition: Transition<in Bitmap>?) {
                   var size: ViewGroup.LayoutParams
                   var bmp1 = resource
                   size = UiHelper.getHeightWidth(this@NewStickerActivity, (w).toInt(), (h).toInt())
                   var resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp1, size.width, size.height, false)
                   var drawable = BitmapDrawable(resources, resizedBitmap)
                   var dsImageSticker = DrawableSticker(drawable)
                   dsImageSticker.setTag("ImageSticker")
                   var pm: List<Int>
                   if (density > 3.0) {
                       pm = UiHelper.getmargins(this@NewStickerActivity, (x).toInt(), (y).toInt())
                   } else {
                       pm = UiHelper.getmargins(this@NewStickerActivity, (x).toInt(), (y).toInt())
                   }
                   Log.i("Hmmm:", pm.get(0).toFloat().toString() + "::" + pm.get(1).toFloat().toString())

                   stickerView.addStickerAndSetMatrix1(
                           dsImageSticker,
                           pm.get(0).toFloat(),
                           pm.get(1).toFloat()
                   )
                i++
                if(i < imagestickers.size){
                    setimagestickers(imagestickers.get(i).path!!, imagestickers.get(i).x!!, imagestickers.get(i).y!!, imagestickers.get(i).width!!, imagestickers.get(i).height!!)
                }
                   else{
                    if(textstickers.isNullOrEmpty()){
                        loader!!.hide()
                    }
                    else {
                        setTextSticker(textstickers.get(j).text!!, Color.parseColor(textstickers.get(j).color), textstickers.get(j).size!!, textstickers.get(j).x!!, textstickers.get(j).y!!)
                    }
                    }
               }

           })
```

However i'm still wondering how can i solve it with coroutines rather than this approach!!!

Comment: Why do you need `launch` call inside `runBlocking`?

Comment: I don't need it i know that but run blocking is not working for me so i was just give it a try with join but didn't seem to help!! @Ircover

Comment: If you just load the images sequentially and synchronously, does it work? (Because in the example apparently you want to avoid any parallelism and just load images sequentially.) May it be that an HTTP request just times out before loading an excessively large image completely?

Comment: @9000 check my updated question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically, you're making async Glide calls without suspending the coroutine until they are done. The first thing you must change is introduce a `suspend fun getImageSticker()`:

```
suspend fun getSticker(path: String): Bitmap =
    suspendCancellableCoroutine { continuation -> Glide
        .with(this@NewStickerActivity)
        .asBitmap()
        .timeout(6000000)
        .load(path)
        .into(object : CustomTarget<Bitmap>() {
            override fun onResourceReady(resource: Bitmap, x: Transition<in Bitmap>?) {
                continuation.resume(resource)
            }
        })
    }
```

Note that this returns a `Bitmap`. Now you can just call it as if it was a regular, blocking function, and use its result from the caller side:

```
suspend fun setimagestickers(path: String, x: Int, y: Int, w: Int, h: Int) {
    val resource = getSticker(path)
    var size: ViewGroup.LayoutParams
    var bmp1 = resource
    size = UiHelper.getHeightWidth(this@NewStickerActivity, (w).toInt(), (h).toInt())
    var resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp1, size.width, size.height, false)

}
```

Now, if you want to parallelize `setimagestickers` calls, launch them in a loop:

```
launch {
    imagestickers.map {
        launch {
            var image = it.path
            var x = it.x
            var y = it.y
            image!!.log()
            setimagestickers(image!!, x!!, y!!, it.width!!, it.height!!)
        }
    }.joinAll()
    textstickers.forEach {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work as expected, after implementing as you said my activity freezes and stops responding

Comment: Yes, that's what happens with questions that have several layers of problems. My answer solves two of them. You showed the code outside of its context, but if you wrote that `runBlocking` in a function that runs on the UI thread, of course it blocked it. Try replacing with `launch`, but you also need the proper `CoroutineScope`.

Comment: Worked perfectly after replacing run blocking with main coroutines scope!!

Answer (score 0):

None of your code will benefit from runBlocking or the coroutines you launch.

If you are aiming to simply process each of your Image type objects in paralellel due to the long running nature of each task, then you can do something like this:

```
fun main() {
    runBlocking {
        imagestickers.map {
            launch {
                var image = it.path
                var x = it.x
                var y = it.y
                image!!.log()
                setimagestickers(image!!, x!!, y!!, it.width!!, it.height!!)
            }
        }.joinAll()
        textstickers.map {
            launch {
                var text = it.text.toString()
                var color = it.color
                var font = it.font
                var size = it.size
                var x = it.x
                var y = it.y
                setTextSticker(text, Color.parseColor(color), size!!, x!!, y!!)
            }
        }.joinAll()
    }
}
```

Why I removed some of the stuff you were doing:

- The nested `runBlocking` calls you had did nothing. `runBlocking means "block until whatever is inside this block is finished". Your for loops were not async, and would run until they were done anyway.
- The first coroutine `launch` you had did nothing as well. You launched it, and then immediately called `join`. This means that you launch a coroutine, but then immediately wait until it is finished before proceeding.

What this does:

- Rather than loops, we map each image object to a list of jobs for concurrently running coroutines.
- We then wait for every job to finish in each list before proceeding to the next list.

Please Note: It does not look like any of your code benefits from having non-blocking IO, in which case, this parralelism will be limited to the amount of threads you have. That fetching of the image will block the thread it is on (regardless of using coroutines) unless you use a non-blocking library that properly yields while it fetches your image.

Comment: Nope this didn't work after applying your suggested changes textstickers list is still being executed before imagestickers list is completed and i know why this is happening when imagestickers list is called images are loaded with glide which eventually take time because it's loaded from server and hence we need to add the gilde code to blocking somehow but how??

Comment: `runBlocking` is not magic. If Glide is running something asynchronously and not actully doing the fetch to completion when you call it, you need to find a way to wait for that to finish. This is a `Glide` library question...